# mysqlclient is not getting installed

Tags: python, mysql-connector

my command prompt is giving this error when i am installing mysql client for my django project.

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

after this error i searched the internet and someone told to download it manually
from the below link
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

but still no solution for using mysql in my django project
please help!!!!!

Comment: Did you try to follow what is says in the error message?